# How to Release Basic And Pro Version of my iPad App?

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store

**I** have develop iPad App in which i need to use **Basic & Pro Version(Full Version)**.The actual scenario is to end-user download basic version from app store first,if end-user wants to use more features of it then click on purchase Pro version button so it directly redirect to the Pro version after in-App Purchase process sucessfull payment.i have attach screenshot of Pro-version features.

[image: Pro-Version Description With Purchase button]

Comment: From your description it's not clear whether you want to have 2 different apps on the store (basic and pro) or one app (basic) with in-app purchase (pro). Apple heavily favours the latter version to reduce app store bloating.

Comment: i release two apps Basic and Pro,if user download pro version then there is no issue,but if user download basic version then what i do the steps to go?

Comment: Link to the app store page of the pro app or display SKStoreProductViewController with the Pro app
https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an in-app purchase from a basic version direct the user to a pro version. The app store doesn't allow that.

You need to have the pro features built into, but locked, in the basic version. When the user makes the in-app purchase within the basic version you set a flag that unlocks the pro features.

The pro version would be the same app, with a different bundle ID, and with the pro features visible and unlocked.